# Chef test-kitchen fails to converge on Debian 7.11 instance

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm currently using Chef's test-kitchen to test my configurations before applying them to my managed nodes.

I've specified Ubuntu 14.04 + 16.04, as well as Debian 7.11 + 8.8 as the platforms to be tested on. I am able to converge my configuration on the Ubuntu 14.04 + 16.04 instances, as well as the Debian 8.8 instance. When attempting to converge on the Debian 7.11 instance, I receive the following error message:

```
kitchen converge jenkins-complete-install-debian-711
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.16.0)
-----> Converging <jenkins-complete-install-debian-711>...
       Preparing files for transfer
       Preparing dna.json
       Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 5.6.4...
       Removing non-cookbook files before transfer
       Preparing validation.pem
       Preparing client.rb
-----> Chef Omnibus installation detected (install only if missing)
       Transferring files to <jenkins-complete-install-debian-711>
       /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.4)
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Converge failed on instance <jenkins-complete-install-debian-711>.  Please see .kitchen/logs/jenkins-complete-install-debian-711.log for more details
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

It seems that:

```
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.4)
```

is the culprit, however I'm not sure what may be causing this error. It looks like Debian 7.11 is supported according to the [bento project on github](https://github.com/chef/bento), so I'd imagine there's something I need to modify on my side to get this to work. Does anybody have any experience using test-kitchen with Debian 7.11?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a followup for anybody who may also run across this issue, I've found the answer. Per [Chef's Github repo](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/5774), it looks like the fix for this issue is clearing out the `~/.kitchen/cache` directory.

Once I cleared this directory of all files i was able to converge my run list on Debian 7.11 as well as Debian 8.8.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same error issue with kitchen dokken. Fixed by removal of existed chef containers:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND   CREATED        STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
391bb1e8fb3b   chef/chef:12       "true"    12 hours ago   Created             chef-12

$ docker rm chef-12
```

after that, issue dissapeared